# OrientDB average over collection

Tags: sql, aggregate, average, orientdb

Im trying orientdb with some simple apps.

In this app I have People (persona) and places to eat (sitio), people go to those places (I store how many times they do) and score them.

Using this query:

```
SELECT *, 
inE('puntua').comida as comida, 
inE('puntua').servicio as servicio, 
inE('puntua').extras as extras
from Sitio
```

I managed to get all places with its scores, but the scores in an array and I cannot apply Avg() function.

[Data Returned By Query](http://paste.ubuntu.com/10208640/)

tldr;

Am I misunderstanding this new Graph modeling technique? or there is a better aproach to get those averages?

[GraphDB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OVABg.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDITED**

```
create class Puntua extends E

create class Sitio extends V

create class Persona extends V

create vertex Persona set name = 'person' # returns #17:0
create vertex Sitio set place = 'mcdonals' # returns #16:0
create vertex Sitio set place = 'burgerking'
create vertex Sitio set place = 'glicinia' # returns #16:2

create edge Puntua from 17:0 to 16:0 set comida = 8, servicio = 9, = extras = 7
create edge Puntua from 17:0 to 16:0 set comida = 8, servicio = 7, = extras = 9
create edge Puntua from 17:0 to 16:2 set comida = 8, servicio = 7, = extras = 9
```

If the above is your situation, I believe the query you're looking for is something like:

```
SELECT *, myAvg(comida), myAvg(servicio), myAvg(extras) 
FROM (
   SELECT place, 
      inE('Puntua').comida as comida, 
      inE('Puntua').servicio as servicio, 
      inE('Puntua').extras as extras
   FROM Sitio
)
```

where myAvg is a javascript function:

```
var graph = orient.getGraph();
var res = graph.command( "sql", "select avg(list) from (select " + list + " as list)");
if(res.length > 0){
    return res[0].getRecord().field('avg');
} else{
    return null;
}
```

like [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ndsdvtvirbun582/Screen%20Shot%202015-02-18%20at%2018.29.51.png?dl=0). (note the list argument)

The output is [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/gmtp6rk0zpdaudv/Screen%20Shot%202015-02-18%20at%2018.35.42.png?dl=0).

Comment: Wouldn't that query return only Sitio (places) that has been "scored" and others be rejected?

Comment: Actually, the problem is that the output of avg is the average of all records and not record by record. See my update.

Comment: Sweet! then i'll assume that there is no way to do it native and gotta make some functions. Thanks @vitornesduarte